# What does [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"LITERAL"] do in an iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, command-line, environment-variables

I am working on an iOS SDK Library project. I see a line there:

```
NSString *commandExecutionTimeout = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT"];
```

What is the purpose of this line? I know that in command line applications, you can use processInfo to get the arguments and environment variables, but how is the iOS Library using this API?

I checked for the string literal all over in the code but couldn't find any references to it in the build settings or any file.

Where may this environment variable be set in an iOS project's context?

Edit: I had also checked if certain arguments were provided in the scheme that I am running, and there were none.

Comment: You can set environment variables when you launch the app under Xcode but not when the app is released. My guess is this is to let you specify different time out values during development/testing

Comment: I checked the xcode scheme manager, with no arguments to be found.

Comment: Is the value not nil then? If you have a script in the build phase, maybe check the  "Show environnement variables in build log" and see if it's there. Also, use a third party "search", like Atom/VisualCode (which see the whole project as text) or simply `grep 'COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT' -R .` ?

Comment: If this is a library, then the `processInfo` is populated from the host application, which this library is used in. Apparently it's just some of the arguments which this library takes into account, and it has to be documented for the "clients"

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *commandExecutionTimeout = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT"];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).